# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"1"' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

**ERROR:**
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"1"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
Property '1' does not exist on type 'Object'.

86         if(res['1']!= null)
~~~~~~~~
87             stats[0] = res['1']
~~~~~~~~

Code: *dashboard.componant.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import * as pluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { max } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {DashboardService} from './dashboard.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  selected: any;
  alwaysShowCalendars: boolean;
  ranges: any = {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
  }
  constructor(private dashboardService : DashboardService) {
    this.alwaysShowCalendars = true;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  public SystemName: string = "Contacts";
  firstCopy = false;
  // data
  public lineChartData: Array<number> = [0,0,0];
  public labelMFL: Array<any> = [
      { data: this.lineChartData,
        label: this.SystemName
      }
  ];
  // labels
  public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['REACHED', 'NOT REACHED', 'NOT REACHABLE'];
  public lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    scales : {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min : 0
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        }],
    },
      plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        align: 'top',
        anchor: 'end',
        //color: "#2756B3",
        color: "#222",
        font: {
          family: 'FontAwesome',
          size: 14
        },
      },
      deferred: false
    },
  };
   _lineChartColors:Array<any> = [{
       backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'red',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'red',
        pointBorderColor: 'red',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'red'
      }];
  public ChartType = 'bar';
  submit()
  {
    const StartDate = this.selected.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    const EndDate = this.selected.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    console.log(StartDate);
    console.log(EndDate);
    const date = {'from_date': StartDate, 'to_date': EndDate }
    this.dashboardService.unique_contacts_reached(date).subscribe(
      
      (res)=>{console.log(res); 
        const stats = [0,0,0];
        if(res['1']!= null) // ERROR accouring from here 
            stats[0] = res['1']
        if(res['2']!= null)
            stats[1] = res['2']
        if(res['3']!= null)
            stats[2] = res['3'] // to here
        this.labelMFL[0].data = stats
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Can't able to find the problem anymore.

Comment: What does the log of `res` show?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

by keeping any to the response would solve the problem

```
    this.dashboardService.unique_contacts_reached(date).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
```

or

```
    this.dashboardService.unique_contacts_reached(date).subscribe(
      (res: Record<string,any>) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
```

after keeping any also if it show error try this

```
    stats[0] = res['1'] as number
```

for all value assignments, as in stats variable you declared numbers as default values